# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener after upgrading JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, classnotfoundexception

We are using below Technologies/frameworks:

1. Spring 2_5 -> Spring 5_0_9
2. JSF 1_2 -> 2_2
3. Java 6 -> Java 8
4. Tomcat 6 -> Tomcat 8_5

Below is the error which i am facing while upgradation process:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
Oct 03, 2018 3:32:59 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 03, 2018 3:33:07 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 03, 2018 3:33:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TEST]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TEST]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of type [com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:647)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1009)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Investigate this: _"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener"_

Comment: @Kukeltje That is because of new jsf-impl.2.2.18 is not having ReflectionUtilsListener (class inside ReflectionUtils class) class which was there in older jsf-impl.

Comment: @Kukeltje: I have investigated that. This ReflectionUtils class is already there in jsf-impl.2.2.18 JAR.

Comment: @AakashPatel: True, It's not having ReflectionUtilsListener class.

Comment: So where in your app are you **still** using jsf 2.2 that it thinks it needs this class? check your deployment, server etc...

Comment: @AnkitJani  Check your code where this class is using. Change all classes which are using this class according to new class.

Comment: @Kukeltje We are migrating from JSF 1.2 to 2.2 (2.3 is typo)

Comment: There's still a JSF 1.2 JAR file lingering somewhere in the runtime classpath. We cannot help you further in detail, because we cannot beam over to your location and check with our own eyes which JAR files exactly are all in the runtime classpath of your application.

Comment: @BalusC I have checked in Tomcat log for all scanned jars. It is taking jar as: *03-Oct-2018 16:55:44.975 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/D:/Apache/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/IUCS/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.18.jar]*
And below that this is the exception we are getting after commenting <listener-class>com.sun.faces.util.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionUtilsListener</listener-class> in jsf_core.tld
Error:
The type specified [com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener] is not one of the expected listener types

Comment: Yeah. Your first step is finding and removing the offending JSF 1.2 JAR file from the runtime classpath of your application. We really can't do more for you with the information given so far and the way how you formulated the question.  Probably you want to formulate your next questions differently. E.g. "What is the runtime classpath?" and Google on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project contains .TLD file from jsf-impl.jar file. Compare it with older jar's TLD. If they both are same, than do this: Open new JAR file from JD-GUI and take new .TLD file and replace with you project's existing TLD than clean everything and try again.